# How useful is dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection

I am new to Dependency Injection, using C#, so please forgive me for my lame question. I wanted to post this question anyway before investing time and buying expensive books on this subject.

After going through a few online documents, it appears that using dependency containers along with configuration files one can use this to swith from one type of implementation to another. However this could be easily done by an if/else statement and some config settings.

What is the advantage of using such a cumbersome implementation just to change from one class to another? I see abstract and factory patterns to be much more useful. Maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ha s a real worl case where i needed dependency injection :

2 assembly : 1 responsible for computing a price when you do a search (lets call it Search), and the second responsible for computing a booking price with all the options (let's call it Booking).

The Booking assembly is already referencing Search(because it needs to know the initial price for computing the full price).

But here is the requirement : we need the price from Search to include all mandatories options  (yes in the tourism industry you have mandatories options) like "full room cleaning".

So I couldn't had a ref to Booking in Search (because of circular reference). So I decided use dependency injection.

My Search assembly defined an interface

```
public interface IAddMandatoryOptionService{
  void ChangeResultsWithMandatoryOptions(SearchResult[] results);
}
```

And then my Booking Assembly could implement this interface.

```
public class AddMandatoryOptionService : IAddMandatoryOptionService{
  public void ChangeResultsWithMandatoryOptions(SearchResult[] results){
  ...
  }
}
```

My SearchService class now would look like

```
public class SearchService{
  public SearchService(IAddMandatoryOptionService optionService){
    this.OptionService = optionService;
  }
  public SearchResult[] Search(Filter filter){
    ...
    this.OptionService.ChangeResultsWithMandatoryOptions(results); 
    ...
    return results;
  }
}
```

So my Search Service has no dependency to the AddMandatoryOptionService class (and the Booking assembly), but it's using its functionality.The good IAddMandatoryOptionService  will be injected when I create my service (in my Application_Start or with a DI Framework)

The advantages are :

- Resolving the circular reference problem.
- If I want to unit test my SearchService I'll juste have to mock/fake IAddMandatoryOptionService.

Here the need for injection was more technical than logical, but I think this kind of real world scenario could help you to get the point.

Answer (score 1):

In short, dependency injection is used to be able to losely couple classes. By using an if else statement you introduce a dependency between classes. When adding à new implementation to your if else statement you need to add another else statement.

You've probably read http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection since they have a pretty good motivation section.

Perhaps complete your q with different code examples.